# Extract Email Address Perl Script

Tags: bash, perl

I have following lines in my `mail.log` file I want to extract domain and generate a output in `txt` file with adding `REJECT` by given space between domain and `REJECT`.

```
Dec 30 07:34:09 mx postfix/smtpd[23855]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[120.33.244.87]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [120.33.244.87]; from=<hcsales6@printingpress.xicp.net> to=`<`nishant@mydomain.com> proto=SMTP helo=<printingpress.xicp.net>
```

The output should be like this

```
printingpress.xicp.net REJECT
```

I have tried this code but this is giving me IP address with REJECT i want domain name to be extracted

```
 perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /NOQUEUE:.*?\[(\d+?\.\d+?\.\d+?\.\d+?)\]/' /var/log/mail.log
```

---

This is the final Result and work scenario, i have postfix server with policy-spf and DKIM running but getting many spam connections and my postfix is rejecting requests nicely. I wanted to block these spammers using smtpd_sender_restrictions, but filtering rejected host is quite time consuming and wanted automation.

Thanks @Polar Bear for the solution. Now the system works like this

postfix main.cf

```
 smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/blacklist
```

blacklist.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
 perl -ne 'print "$1 REJECT\n" if /NOQUEUE:\s+reject:.*?from=<\w+@(.*?)>/' /var/log/mail.log | sort | uniq >> /etc/postfix/blacklist
 postmap /etc/postfix/blacklist
 service postfix restart
```

Giving permission to the file

```
 chmod 755 blacklist.sh
```

Running cronjob for blacklist.sh every night.

I tried the same code with few modifications and running nother cronjob every 3 hrs for SASL Failed Logins and blockhole IP addresses.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @SachinG. : I don't quite understand: You are **explicitly looking** for an IP address pattern (`(\d+?\.\d+?\.\d+?\.\d+?)`) in your code. Why do you expect this would return you the mail address?

Comment: @user1934428 when i tried adding from in the code it doesn't show any output.

Comment: I don't get you. As Cyrus said, you should post what you tried to extract the email address. Instead you posted what you tried to extract the IP address. We need to see the actual code you are attempting.

Comment: @SachinG.: Are you just looking for `perl -nle 'print "$1 REJECT" if /.*helo=<(.*)>/'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner

In Windows 10 (Straberry Perl)

`perl -ne "print \"$1 REJECT\n\" if $_ =~ /NOQUEUE:\s+reject:.*?helo=<(.*)>/" /var/log/mail.log`

In Debian 8 [perl (v5.20.2)]

`perl -ne 'print "$1 REJECT\n" if /NOQUEUE:\s+reject:.*?helo=<(.*)>/' /var/log/mail.log`

OP informed that *domain* should be taken from field **from** and one record per domain, then command should be altered in the following form

`perl -ne 'print "$1 REJECT\n" if /NOQUEUE:\s+reject:.*?from=<\w+@(.*?)>/' /var/log/mail.log | sort | uniq`

or extended code version

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 1;

my %hash;

my $pattern = qr/(\w+\s+\d+)\s+([\d:]+).*?:\s+NOQUEUE:\s+(\w+):.*?\[([\d.]+)\]:\s+(\d+).*?:\s+(.*?),.*?from=<(.*?)>\s+to=<(.*?)>.*?helo=<(.*)>/;

my @fields = qw/date time state ip code err_msg from to fqdn/;

my $line = <DATA>;
chomp($line);

@hash{@fields} = ($line =~ /$pattern/);

print $hash{fqdn}. ' '. uc $hash{state} . "\n";

print Dumper(\%hash) if $debug;

__DATA__
Dec 30 07:34:09 mx postfix/smtpd[23855]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[120.33.244.87]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [120.33.244.87]; from=<hcsales6@printingpress.xicp.net> to=<nishant@mydomain.com> proto=SMTP helo=<printingpress.xicp.net>
```

output

```
printingpress.xicp.net REJECT
$VAR1 = {
          'state' => 'reject',
          'from' => 'hcsales6@printingpress.xicp.net',
          'time' => '07:34:09',
          'code' => '450',
          'ip' => '120.33.244.87',
          'to' => 'nishant@mydomain.com',
          'date' => 'Dec 30',
          'err_msg' => 'cannot find your hostname',
          'fqdn' => 'printingpress.xicp.net'
        };
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205067/discussion-on-answer-by-polar-bear-extract-email-address-perl-script).

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
my $input = 'Dec 30 07:34:09 mx postfix/smtpd[23855]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[120.33.244.87]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [120.33.244.87]; from=<hcsales6@printingpress.xicp.net> to=`<`nishant@mydomain.com> proto=SMTP helo=<printingpress.xicp.net>';

my ($val, $domain) = $input=~m/NOQUEUE\:\s*([^\:]+)\:.+?helo\=<([^>]+)\>/i;

print ": $val\t$domain\n";
```

Comment: Thanks i tied this code and gave me nice output but what i want is to use local file /var/log/mail.log and instead of helo i want from email address. I tried changing the my $input and it throw error Use of uninitialized value $domain in concatenation (.) or string